# Is there dynamic binding in XQuery?

Tags: sql, oop, xquery, dynamic-programming, xquery-3.0

I am studying XQuery and how it is used to query XML documents along with SQL and I learned that XQuery version 1.0 does not support dynamic binding or object oriented design which means XQuery is not very useful for large programs. I might be mistaken but wasn't dynamic binding introduced in XQuery 3.0 ? if so can you give a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the [Higher Order Functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#higher-order-functions):

[fn:function-lookup()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-function-lookup) Returns the function having a given name and arity, if there is one.

> The expression `fn:function-lookup(xs:QName('fn:substring'), 2)('abcd', 2)` returns '`bcd`'.

[fn:function-name()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-function-name) Returns the name of the function identified by a function item.

> The expression `fn:function-name(fn:substring#2)` returns `fn:QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions", "fn:substring")`. (The namespace prefix of the returned QName is not predictable.).

[fn:function-arity()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-function-arity) Returns the arity of the function identified by a function item.

> The expression `fn:function-arity(fn:substring#2)` returns `2`.

[fn:apply()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-apply)

> The expression `fn:apply(fn:concat#3, ["a", "b", "c"])` returns "`abc`".

Comment: thank you. so does this mean we can use XQuery with object oriented framework?

Comment: Maybe. It might be easier to answer if you named the framework or had a concrete example of what you want to achieve. However, beware that XQuery is a functional language. You might be able to use it with an OO framework, but just because you can doesn’t necessarily mean that you should.

Comment: thank you. I thought that XQuery doesn't support creating objects. thanks for making that clear. I was thinking about how xml is built in Oracle and data-centric models and I was wondering how XQuery handled this type of data.

Answer (score 2):

When using a language like XQuery, try to avoid forcing it into a different paradigm: don't try to use an approach that works with one language (or family of languages) when that's not appropriate.

Languages are built around data models, and the XDM data model is built around XML, and XML was designed for document markup. That affects the mindset of the designers and to use it successfully you need to understand that mindset. It's not object-oriented because documents aren't object-oriented.

XQuery 1.0, as you say, has no dynamic binding or polymorphism, and that does make certain problems difficult to tackle (documents certainly are often very polymorphic). That's probably why XSLT has retained its popularity in competition. There's a reason, of course, which is that XQuery, because it's statically analyzable, is very amenable to the kind of optimizations which make a huge difference when you're querying large databases.

XQuery 3.0 has introduced dynamic binding through the mechanism of first-class functions. It's a different approach from the inheritance and polymorphism of object-oriented languages, but it's equally powerful, and it has the advantage that it doesn't get in the way of static optimization when you don't use it.